# How to implement FTP with Laravel 5?

Tags: php, ftp, laravel-5

I see there's a package Flysystem
https://packagist.org/packages/graham-campbell/flysystem

But when I try to run:

```
$ composer require graham-campbell/flysystem
```

I got the following error. I paste it later.

Maybe that's because of my Laravel version 5.0.33 that need to be updated to 5.1?

Or Maybe  that's because of  my requirements, as error tells, (which ones)?

----------------- ERROR --------------------

```
Using version ^3.1 for graham-campbell/flysystem
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
**Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.**

  Problem 1
- Installation request for graham-campbell/flysystem ^3.1 -> satisfiable by graham-campbell/flysystem[v3.1.0].
- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.0.33
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.33
- graham-campbell/flysystem v3.1.0 requires illuminate/support 5.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.1.1, v5.1.2, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
- don't install illuminate/support v5.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.33
- don't install illuminate/support v5.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.33
- don't install illuminate/support v5.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.33
- don't install illuminate/support v5.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.33
- Installation request for laravel/framework == 5.0.33.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.0.33].
```

**Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.**

Comment: The is telling you that the version of the package you're trying to install *requires* Laravel 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Flysystem comes with Laravel 5 by default so you don't need to install it as a package, that's why you are getting an error because it conflicts with the existing package.

It's documented in the filesystem section... http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/filesystem

Comment: Ok but going back to my "Ftp" problem... I've already seen this page but it doesn't tell anything about setting up a Ftp Driver in Filesystem in order to use it with Storage....

Comment: Read the section about the custom filesystems, then inject the FTP Adapter http://flysystem.thephpleague.com/adapter/ftp/